# Stop the default bulleted list on new slides in Impress

Tags: default-settings, list, libreoffice-impress

In every version of Libre Office Impress I can recall (including the current 7.6), making a new slide always defaults to a layout with a text box initiated with an unordered, bulleted list. Is there any way to change that default to not start new slides with a list?

You can see the starting default bullet in the screenshot below, in an otherwise virgin new presentation, having used the "New Slide" command. Both the vanilla new-presentation and all of the provided template styles exhibit this same behavior.

[image: Impress New Slide with default starting unordered bullet list]

Among the things I've used as workarounds: The most common is to copy-paste an existing slide, with non-list-format text, to use as a starting basis. But it seems odd that this is easier than using the new-slide command, and it risks unintentionally duplicating forward other unwanted styles, notes, etc.

One can make a new slide and then immediately exit out of the list format by clicking on Format > Lists > Unordered List, which toggles off the list state (removing the initial bullet & indent, etc.). But the interface seems opaque on what this action does, there seems to be no hotkey for it, and it seems weird to need this redundant step on every new slide to get to a basic-nonlist-text mode.

One can view the Master Slide and edit the list style to hide the initial bullet and indent. But that winds up messing with your ability to actually create a bulleted list later when you do want one, and confuses knowing whether your format state is actually unlisted, versus in the default list with no bullet.

For me, this unwanted bullet list on any new slide causes me to avoid the "New Slide" command entirely, and instead I'm constantly copying an old slide without the list formatting, and cutting and editing those. Is there any way to change that default?